# How to change element position in Desktop vs Mobile resolution?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have page with sidebar. Sidebar has some element on desktop. On mobile sidebar moves under main page. But I want that element to be above main page on mobile, like so:

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just about placement of elements in Desktop vs Mobile resolutions then you can do it by adding `pull-right` Bootstrap class on right side elements ad shown in below snippet:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.elem,
.main,
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.elem {
  height: 150px;
}

.main {
  height: 400px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right elem">Element</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 main">Main Page</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me

Comment: @DimitriiRybakov you are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could achieve that using `css media query`. On desktop view it keep your `.mainpage` at left, `.element` and `.sidebar` at right, now if viewport `width<=640px` then it aligns your element at top and then as follows.

```css
.mainpage{
 width:50%;
 height:400px;
 background:#f1f;
 float:left;
}
.element{
 width:50%;
 height:200px;
 background:#f22;
 float:right;
}
.sidebar{
 width:50%;
 height:200px;
 background:#ccc;
 float:right;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 640px){
  .mainpage{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
  }
    .element{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="element">element</div>
<div class="mainpage">main page</div>
<div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
```